# Invert the scale of an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Say I have the following array:

```
x = np.array([3,7,1,2,6])
```

What is the simplest way to obtain the array with its scale say in the inverse way? So the minimum value would become the maximum, the maximum would become the minimum, and so on for the rest of the values.

Expected ouput:

```
array[3,1,7,6,2]
```

To clarify on what I want to obtain, say my original sequence is:

```
y = sorted(x)
#[1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

So the array sorted. If this was the case, the array that I would want is the array reversed, so `[7, 6, 3, 2, 1]`. I want to accomplish this with my current input.

Therefore, where I had the lowest value, `1` is now a `7`, the second lowest vaule, `2` is now a `6`, and so on.

Comment: They have a logical way to do this... `x*-1`. apart from that I don't understand how this could be a good thing

Comment: I really don't understand your expected output. How is it related to your input? Why is 3 unchanged?

Comment: @Bazingaa the largest value `7` should become the lowest, `1`, the second largest should become the second lowerst, `2`and so on

Comment: why would taking the opposite sign of the numbers not solve this problem.

Comment: Well in that case, if you are changing the scale, 3 should become 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a numpy way:

```
np.sort(x)[::-1][np.argsort(np.argsort(x))]
```

Why this works: Suppose your list were already sorted, then you would just need to reverse it. Since the list isn't sorted we can first sort it, then reverse it, and then undo our sort.

Improvment: We really only need to compute `argsort` once. Then `x` can be sorted with this list and we can compute the inverse permutation to `argsort(x)` without another sort.

```
ax = np.argsort(x)
aax = np.zeros(len(ax),dtype='int')
aax[ax] = np.arange(len(ax),dtype='int')

x[ax[::-1]][aax]
```

Answer (score 2):

If the input values are unique:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([3, 7, 1, 2, 6])

s = sorted(x)
lookup = {v: i for v, i in zip(s, reversed(s))}

result = np.array(list(map(lookup.get, x)))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[3 1 7 6 2]
```

If I understood correctly you want to assign to each value in the sorted order the value in the same position in the reverse sorted order.

Comment: Care to explain/add explanation to your logic in the code?

Answer (score 0):

here's my first thought:

```
In [13]: xr=np.zeros_like(x)

In [14]: g=0

In [15]: f=np.unique(sorted(x))

In [16]: for b in f:
             g-=1
             #for repeated values:
             for y in np.where(x==b)[0]:
                 xr[y]=f[g]
    ...:     
In [17]: xr
Out[17]: array([3, 1, 7, 6, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I invert np array value (biggest value->smallest value, smallest value -> biggest) without sorting.

```py
np_arr_inv = np_arr * -1 + np_arr.max()
```

I need to keep the order since it is image data.

FYI Numpy has a bit-wise inversion function [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html)